Martial arts movie where a fighter runs across the face of a building
This movie is in a modern setting. A urban city.
The martial artists in this film can run up city buildings etc... I remember in the opening the girl in the movie (daughter of one of the grand martial artists) is trying to see something and runs across the face of several tall buildings.
It has a young man in it. He has glasses (can't see well) and asthma I think. He meets a girl and she knows martial arts. She is trained by grand masters, that blend in the world. I think one is like a cab driver or something base. 
Some great powerful martial artist returns and beats the crap out of all the grand martial artists that were training the kid and the girl that he likes. The girl is like the child of one of the grand martial artist and is WAY better than he is...
I remember he ends up beating the guy in the end (dur). 

Welcome to the site. If you could include a little detail about the movie, as in, was it dubbed from some other language to English, or what. Also, when was the movie put out (what year did you see it always helps). Any notable actors? Anything can help.

Was this a Chinese movie? It sounds like it, especially if you mean that they're 'flying' over rooftops when you say "run across faces of buildings". Also, how far from realistic (aside from the fighting itself and the running against/over buildings) is the movie?


Arahan (2004)

Sang-hwan (Seung-beom Ryu) is a well meaning but cowardly Korean
  policeman. By chance, he meets a mysterious group of old men called
  the 'Seven Masters' who protect the earth from ancient evil. Centuries
  ago, the Seven Masters imprisoned HeugUn – the master of absolute evil
  – but now HeugUn has returned to seek bloody vengeance on all mankind.
  Teamed with the beautiful but deadly Eui-jin, Sang hwan must not only
  fight for his own life, but to protect the fate of all men. ---
  Synopsis from SBS.com.au


Here's the girl you mentioned. We first see her in a convenience store (right after the opening credits), then she gets a ''flash''.

The spectacled guy appears soon after... he's the cop who halts the car. Skip to the 0:06:40 mark in the video for more rooftop action :-)
